# Arrayformula does not recognize date in cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I'm using an apps script function to update the "last_contacted" cell from 'PENDING' to a timestamp using a function containing:

```
function updateRow(singleRowJson,headerRow,columnToUpdate,value ) 


  var cell = sheet.getRange(absoluteRow, columnNumber+1); // here cell is C2
  cell.setValue(value);
```

I pass in :

```
 updateRow(pendingRow,'3','last_contacted',new Date() )
```

elsewhere and this appears to work fine.

Now I want to have a daily tracker 'days since' which keeps track of the days since the timestamp next door.

I have the following array formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(ISDATE(V4:V),DATEDIF(V4:V,TODAY(),"D"),"no"))
```

in U4. assuming today is 12/10 you can see the result. How can I get this working?

edit:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, you did say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an alternative:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(Today()-V4:V=today(),"no",Today()-V4:V))
```

Comment: Thank you. that works! Any tips on why does yours work and not mine?